# How to write this particular sql statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I currently have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 column_name 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY voteColumn DESC
```

"voteColumn" is integer based. People from my app hit +1 or -1 and feedback is calculated based on current value in "voteColumn".

But there is a problem because there are records which don't have a feedback yet, and their default value is "0". I don't want to show those records. So basically I'm asking is , how to convert this statement into a SQL statement if possible:

```
SELECT TOP 10 column_name 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY voteColumn Desc -> but not return any column_name if value is "0" or return only those who value is above "0".
```

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Null is probably a better indicator of no value than zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 10 column_name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE voteColumn <> 0
ORDER BY voteColumn Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT TOP 10 column_name FROM table_name   
  WHERE voteColumn > 0   
  ORDER BY voteColumn Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output results where the voteColumn value is greater than 0, then you just need a WHERE statement.

```
SELECT TOP 10 column_name FROM table_name 
WHERE voteColumn > 0
ORDER BY voteColumn Desc
```